# IntegrityError in django duplicated key

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-errors

Hello I have a form on django that im trying to validate so it does not allow duplicated values, as of right now when you enter a duplicated value it raises this error on the app:

```
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
duplicate key violates uniqueness restriction «utiles_employee_user_id_key»
DETAIL:  The key already exists (user_id)=(3).
```

**Here's my form:**

```
class EmployeeForm(Form):
    first_name = CharField(max_length=40, label=_('Nombre'))
    last_name = CharField(max_length=40, label=_('Apellido'))
    children = IntegerField(label=_('Cantidad de Hijos'), required=False)
    email2 = EmailField(label=_('Correo electrónico personal'), required=False)
    email = EmailField(label=_('Correo electrónico Corporativo'))
    company = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Company.objects.all(), required=False, label=_('Empleado de'))

    def __init__(self, data=None, files=None, auto_id='id_%s', prefix=None, initial=None, error_class=ErrorList,
                 label_suffix=None, empty_permitted=False, user=None):
        super().__init__(data, files, auto_id, prefix, initial, error_class, label_suffix, empty_permitted)
        if not user.is_staff:
            self.fields['company'].queryset = Company.objects.filter(id=user.employee.company.id)
```

how can I raise an error message saying to the user that it entered a duplicated object, as of right now the app crashes when I do.

EDIT:
I added this method to the form but the problem persist.

```
    def clean(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user = Employee.objects.get(email2=cd)
        if self.instance and not user == self.instance:
            raise ValidationError('trial msg')
        return cd
```

but now i get this error:

```
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'EmployeeForm' object has no attribute 'instance'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired behavior using the `clean` method. This method is present either on the `Field` definition itself and also on the `Form`.

You can find more detailed information on Django's documentation:

- [Cleaning using the FormField itself](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/validation/#form-field-default-cleaning)
- [Cleaning a specific form attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute)
- [More general form cleaning](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other)

By raising a `ValidationError` when the duplicate data is present, it will allow you to detect the issue in the view and then display/render the desired error message.

Comment: I added a clean method but still not luck, now it raises an AttributeError type